# Copying Source Directory to a shared network folder within a TFS Build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, unc

I am trying to copy all the files within my source folder in a TFS collection to a VM that I have set up. The VM has a shared folder I can access within the file explorer by typing `\\*IPAddress*\share` (where IPAddress is the IP of the VM).

- I tried to copy the source folder by adding a "Copy Files" build task in TFS 2015.
- In the `Source Folder` section I have added the folder that I wish to copy.
- In the `Contents` section I have left it as `**` to get each file within the `Source Folder`
- In `Target Folder` I have put the address that I can navigate to within the file explorer : `\\*IPAddress*\share` (where IPAddress is the IP of the VM)

When I queue the build and run it I get the following error:

```
Unable to create directory '\\*IPAddress*\share'. Unable to verify the directory exists: '\\*IPAddress*\share'. If directory is a file share, please verify the share name is correct, the share is online, and the current process has permission to access the share.
```

When I hover of the the little "I" next to target folder it states that it can be a UNC Path, so I know I'm able to copy the files but I'm not sure if I'm referencing the share folder correctly.

How would I reference this? One thing that may also be giving an issue is that when I navigate to the share from the File Explorer I have to enter credentials to access the share folder, so maybe it doesn't have permission to access the share because of this.

Comment: Use the `Windows Machine File Copy` task for this, not `Copy Files`. It will handle authenticating, mapping a share, and copying the files for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested and [`Windows Machine File Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=vsts) task works for me with providing the credential to access the shared path.

For `Copy Files` task, you can try to grant the **Read** and **Write** permissions for the build agent service account (Which you specified during deploy the agent), then try it again.

Besides, you can also create a script to copy the files, then add a command line or PowerShell task to run the script.

For example, you can use below PowerShell script to copy the sources files with the specific username and password provided:

```
$Source = $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY
$Dest   = "\\172.17.16.115\CopyTest"
$Username = "domain\username"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "PasswordHere" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $Password)
New-PSDrive -Name J -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Dest -Credential $mycreds -Persist
Copy-Item -Path $Source -Recurse -Force -Destination $Dest
```